# How to store [name,value] pairs in database (MySQL) in a single column/field of a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a table in which one of the field is a threshold value.This threshold value is actually  name/value pairs for one entity and i would like to store this name/value pairs in one field.
How could I do this?I dont want to have a seperate table for key/value pairs.Please provide your comments..
I will be using JPA and Hibernate for implementation.

Comment: "*I dont want to have a seperate table for key/value pairs*" - why is that so?

Comment: Will I be able to resolve my problems with that?If so then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD probably separate name and value in differents fields / tables. Please explain us why you don't want ...

However, if you have good reasons, juste separate the key / value by a "special character", like `|` or any charachter you can't have in `name` nor `value`. But this is a dangerous method...

Comment: If i agree to seperate out the name and values, then how could i achieve the solution?